# Storing IP addresses in SQLite using C# and ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, ado.net, sql-function

I've got a database client that will connect to a MySQL database. Much like the MySQL Workbench, I have a system in place to store connection credentials so that they can be called up later. I'm implementing this feature on my own in C#.

I have a WPF form in which these details would be entered. One of these controls takes in the IP address, which I'd like to store in a SQLite3 database file. Problem is, when I put the txtHostname.Text from the form and store it in the table (the particular column is a text-type column), it trips up on the "." between the digits in the IP address.

Let's say I'm using 127.0.0.1. The database will store up to 127, come across the ".0", and throw an error in the C#. This is a problem, of course.

Here's the code I'm using to create the .db file and create a table to hold information in:

```
    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = txtConnectionName.Text + ".db";
        SQLiteConnection conn = CreateConnectionForSchemaCreation(fileName);

        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Server_Details(ConnectionName TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Hostname TEXT NOT NULL, Username TEXT NOT NULL, Password TEXT NOT NULL, DefaultSchema TEXT NOT NULL)";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO Server_Details(ConnectionName,Hostname,Username,Password,DefaultSchema) VALUES({0},{1},{2},{3},{4})", txtConnectionName.Text, txtHostname.Text, txtUsername.Text, pwdPassword.Password, txtDefaultSchema.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

I'm really more of a developer than a database analyst, so I'm a bit stumped here. I'd rather use the SQLite database to hold this information - it's far easier to work with than parsing a .txt file - but it would seem as if the data type to natively hold IP addresses isn't there in SQLite. I know I could possibly write a function to enable that, but it's been a while since I've done any SQL function work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you quote your variables, they'll be treated as literal values.

This gives me a syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO Server_Details VALUES (Google, google.com, foo, bar, 127.0.0.1);
```

This executes just fine:

```
INSERT INTO Server_Details VALUES ('Google', 'google.com', 'foo', 'bar', '127.0.0.1');
```

*Really*, though, this is a good time to talk about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). If you pass the query and its data separately, you can avoid quite a few bugs, security problems, and performance hits.

You didn't mention which particular DBI you're using (there are several SQLite libraries for C#), but you can find a pretty good explanation of prepared statements [right here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-prepared-statements-can-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks). You might check your library's documentation for any mention of "prepared statements" or "binding variables".

Comment: It's the official one available through NuGet... System.Data.SQLite, if I recall correctly.

Comment: As for the variables, would it be possible to implement them in this fashion:

`string hostname = "'" + txtHostname.txt + "'";`

And insert "hostname" instead of the `txtHostname.txt` value I'm using now?

Comment: That should work fine. Or, since you're using `string.Format()`, you can change `{4}` to `'{4}'`.

Comment: While that will technically work, it is still vulnerable to SQL injection.  A good next step would be to replace all apostrophe's in textboxes with a pair of apostrophes